# Improving a tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have drawn the following picture with tikz:

[image]

Code for MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage,oneside,reqno]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.45in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PSL}{L}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PSU}{U}
\DeclareMathOperator{\M}{M}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0,
height=9.27cm,
width=15cm,
ymajorgrids,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={},
ytick={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
yticklabels={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
xticklabels={$A_5$,$\PSL_2(7)$,$A_6$,$\PSL_2(8)$,$\PSL_2(11)$,$\PSL_2(13)$,$\PSL_2(17)$,$A_7$,$\PSL_2(19)$,$\PSL_2(16)$,$\PSL_3(3)$,$\PSU_3(3)$,$\PSL_2(23)$,$\PSL_2(25)$,$\M_{11}$,$\PSL_2(27)$},
ylabel=$\mathfrak{p}$,
]    

\addplot+[]
coordinates {
(1,0.247343) 
(2,0.189913) 
(3,0.0833901) 
(4,0.0613976) 
(5,0.05859) 
(6,0.0290478) 
(7,0.0173417) 
(8,0.0279725) 
(9,0.0137492) 
(10,0.0176165) 
(11,0.0304418) 
(12,0.0155998) 
(13,0.00976193) 
(14,0.00851869) 
(15,0.0119328) 
(16,0.00731549) 

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The subgroup permutability degree of all finite simple groups of small order. The $x$-axis lists the groups in increasing order.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am primarily interested in hearing suggestions what to do with the overlapping labels of the $x$-axis, but I'd also appreciate input on how to improve the overall aesthetics of the picture, if anyone cares to share his/her opinion.

Comment: I would put the marks on the axes away, and use vertical full lines instead, coloured in light gray like the horizontal ones. It would made the graph more readable. A least that's what I would do if I had to draw this. Only I don't know enough about Tikz ;-) being primarily a MetaPost user, but I suppose it is easy enough to achieve with Tikz/PGF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the size and/or rotate the labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage,oneside,reqno]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.45in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PSL}{L}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PSU}{U}
\DeclareMathOperator{\M}{M}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0,
height=9.27cm,
width=15cm,
ymajorgrids,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={},
ytick={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
yticklabels={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
xticklabels={$A_5$,$\PSL_2(7)$,$A_6$,$\PSL_2(8)$,$\PSL_2(11)$,$\PSL_2(13)$,$\PSL_2(17)$,$A_7$,$\PSL_2(19)$,$\PSL_2(16)$,$\PSL_3(3)$,$\PSU_3(3)$,$\PSL_2(23)$,$\PSL_2(25)$,$\M_{11}$,$\PSL_2(27)$},
ylabel=$\mathfrak{p}$,
]    

\addplot+[]
coordinates {
(1,0.247343) 
(2,0.189913) 
(3,0.0833901) 
(4,0.0613976) 
(5,0.05859) 
(6,0.0290478) 
(7,0.0173417) 
(8,0.0279725) 
(9,0.0137492) 
(10,0.0176165) 
(11,0.0304418) 
(12,0.0155998) 
(13,0.00976193) 
(14,0.00851869) 
(15,0.0119328) 
(16,0.00731549) 

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0,
height=9.27cm,
width=15cm,
ymajorgrids,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={},
ytick={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
yticklabels={0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25},
xticklabel style={rotate=90,font=\footnotesize},
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
xticklabels={$A_5$,$\PSL_2(7)$,$A_6$,$\PSL_2(8)$,$\PSL_2(11)$,$\PSL_2(13)$,$\PSL_2(17)$,$A_7$,$\PSL_2(19)$,$\PSL_2(16)$,$\PSL_3(3)$,$\PSU_3(3)$,$\PSL_2(23)$,$\PSL_2(25)$,$\M_{11}$,$\PSL_2(27)$},
ylabel=$\mathfrak{p}$,
]    

\addplot+[]
coordinates {
(1,0.247343) 
(2,0.189913) 
(3,0.0833901) 
(4,0.0613976) 
(5,0.05859) 
(6,0.0290478) 
(7,0.0173417) 
(8,0.0279725) 
(9,0.0137492) 
(10,0.0176165) 
(11,0.0304418) 
(12,0.0155998) 
(13,0.00976193) 
(14,0.00851869) 
(15,0.0119328) 
(16,0.00731549) 

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]